pasar array json a datatable y manipular sus valores (como se hace en foreach)
Hola a todos esperoe sten bien, mi consulta es la siguiente
tengo este array que se arma en un while.. y luego lo pasa a un json
while($data = $query->fetch_object()){
    // Poner los datos en un array en el orden de los campos de la tabla
    $data_array[] = array($data->id_info, $data->placa_info, $data->fecha_info, $data->sp, $data->hf, $data->hg, $data->rutaad, $data->fallos, $data->viajes_m);
}
// crear un array con el array de los datos, importante que esten dentro de : data
$new_array  = array("data"=>$data_array);
// crear el JSON apartir de los arrays
echo json_encode($new_array);

como hago para que un array o json aparezca en una dupla tipo
foreach($data as $key => $user){ 
                            
                ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo "<a href=editar.php?id_info=$user[id_info] target=_parent>".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($user['fecha_info']))."</a>"; ?></td>
.....
.....
}

ya que necesito armar y mostrar los valores en el datatable con los datos de la consulta y manipular los valores (como por ejemplo poner enlace etc... mientras que con el json ese puro no me da esa opción
Llevo este código pero no me resulta al parecer monto mal el array o no se que...
   $con = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "clave", "basededatos");
$data_array = array();
$sql = "select * FROM tabla";
$query = $con->query($sql);
    while ($data = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
  {   
  $data_array[] = '<a href=javascript:ventanaeditgdatapequenaw2("editardocumentosactualizar.php?id='.$data["id_info"].'&pestana=pestana7")>'."<font color=\'#000000\'>".$data["id_info"].'</font></a>';
  $data_array[] = '<a href=javascript:ventanaeditgdatapequenaw2("editardocumentosactualizar.php?id='.$data["id_info"].'&pestana=pestana7")>'."<font color=\'#000000\'>".$data["fecha_info"].'</font></a>';
  $data_array[] = '<a href=javascript:ventanaeditgdatapequenaw2("editardocumentosactualizar.php?id='.$data["id_info"].'&pestana=pestana7")>'."<font color=\'#000000\'>".$data["placa_info"].'</font></a>';
  $data_array[] = '<a href=javascript:ventanaeditgdatapequenaw2("editardocumentosactualizar.php?id='.$data["id_info"].'&pestana=pestana7")>'."<font color=\'#000000\'>".$data["sp"]." ".$data["hf"]." ".$data["hg"].'</font></a>';
  $data_array[] = '<a href=javascript:ventanaeditgdatapequenaw2("editardocumentosactualizar.php?id='.$data["id_info"].'&pestana=pestana7")>'."<font color=\'#000000\'>".$data["rutaad"].'</font></a>';
  $data_array[] = '<a href=javascript:ventanaeditgdatapequenaw2("editardocumentosactualizar.php?id='.$data["id_info"].'&pestana=pestana7")>'."<font color=\'#000000\'>".$data["fallos"].'</font></a>';
}
$json_data = array(
            "draw"=> intval( $requestData['draw'] ), 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ), 
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), 
            "data" => $data_array
            );
echo json_encode($json_data);


Prueba con $data_array["data"][] = array($data->id_info, $data->placa_info, blablabla

No se entiende la pregunta. Tú hablas de querer pasar tus filas bajo una clave data, supongo que para consumir esos datos en el cliente usando DataTables. Si tal es el caso, es más simple de lo que parece: cambia el método fetch_object() por fetch_assoc(), llena tu array de filas y finalmente emite la salida bajo una clave data. Algo así:  $data_array=[]; while($data = $query->fetch_assoc()){ $data_array[] = $data; } $new_array['data'][] = $data_array; echo json_encode($new_array);

@A.Cedano No hace falta incluir las claves en el array para que funcione el Datatables, de hecho no lo recomiendo para no incrementar la transferencia de los datos pasados a Datatables pues son redundantes, considero mejor tan solo pasar los valores.

Hola a todos he puesto una modificación en el código que hace la consulta es decir loaddata.php pero no se por que no me arroja ningún resultado creo que es en el array donde esta el problema (esta en la parte final de mi código)

Si a todo lo llamas $data estás reusando la variable y alli tienes el problema seguramente.

y seria como..?? mil gracias por responder!!

Quita esta definición $data = array(); antes del while, también quita esto: $data[] = $data_array; al final del while, por último, en $json_data, cambia esto: "data" => $data por esto: "data" => $data_array. En resumen, $data debe ser solamente la definición de cada fila que obtienes al recorrer con while el conjunto de resultados. Los demás usos de esa variable no tienen ningún sentido.

sigue sin funcionar no entiendo por que esto si sirve...
while($data = $query->fetch_object()){   $data_array[] = array($data->id_info, $data->placa_info, $data->fecha_info, $data->sp, $data->hf, $data->hg, $data->rutaad, $data->fallos, $data->viajes_m); } $new_array  = array("data"=>$data_array); echo json_encode($new_array);
pero el código con las modificaciones que me dices NO..!!!
puse el código modificado en el mensaje principal con los cambios queme dices a ver en que metí la pata
quiero es que los datos sirvan como enlaces ya que en el codigo que si funciona No se como

Aparte de los errores que ya tienes, yo me pregunto porque quieres escribir ese churro de enlaces en lugar de pasar tan solo los datos y generar el churro en las definiciones del datatable directamente.  Lee un poco más sobre Datatables y te ahorrarás esos json tan cargados de datos innecesarios, y en tu caso necesitas aprender sobre columns.render

Si no necesitas los nombres de columna. Intenta algo así: $data_array=[]; while($data = $query->fetch_assoc()){ $data_array[] = array_values($data); } $new_array = ["data"=>$data_array]; echo json_encode($new_array); Y, como bien dice @masterguru, no tiene sentido generar del lado del servidor todos esos enlaces. Los puedes generar del lado del cliente. Sea con alguna herramienta de que disponga DataTables, sea manualmente. No te líes tanto con el código. Simplemente, al usar array_values() te creará por cada fila un array con los datos de esa fila.

@masterguru gracias por responder aca el problema es que estoy aprendiendo con ustedes, ese es el churro pues si me enseñas de una manera distinta a como escribes aprendo mejor... como hago enlaces en los resultados entonces. ya que Datatable asi solo me muestra los datos..??

Aquí no estamos para enseñarte todos los pasos que vayas haciendo, lo siento. Es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas precisas, y si vas modificando la pregunta cada vez que avanzas en tus pasos entonces sí que parece que te estemos dando clases, lo cual invalida las preguntas y las respuestas previamente dadas, confundiendo a los siguientes visitantes.  Te recomiendo que cada pregunta que hagas, una vez solucionada, no la modifiques, sinó que pases a una siguiente en este sitio, y así crearás más interés en responderte. Dicho esto tan solo te estoy indicando un posible camino que puedes tomar.

Si quieres tomar ese camino pues tendrás que leerte todo ese enlace que te he dado y mirar de comprenderlo.  Y si no lo quieres hacer lo entiendo, no pasa nada. Y si quieres hacerlo entonces adelante, y cuando te encalles haces una nueva pregunta con el problema que te haya surgido, pero no modificando esta continuamente para irla adaptando a tus progresos.

@masterguru aja asi es como usted diga señor!! mil gracias en serio a todos por su ayuda en otros foros se explica y se enseña pues en parte yo he aprendido de todos..

No lo digo yo, lo dicen estos enlaces:  [ask], [tour], [example], [help], etc... Y ya deberias saber que este sitio no es un foro. Es un sitio de preguntas concretas y respuestas a dichas preguntas, las cuales pueden ser modificadas si surgen dudas, pero no si las cambias añadiendo nuevos escenarios que difieren demasiado del inicial.
